# ItextSharp Aligning an image within a pdfstamped rectangle

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to add a banner image to the bottom of my existing pdf page using the pdfstamper.
I have got it displaying but I cannot work out how to get it to align center.

My code is as follows:

```
  using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true))
            {
                var cropbox = reader.GetCropBox(1);
                float left = cropbox.Left;

                iTextSharp.text.Image bannerImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bannerUrl);
                var rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5, cropbox.Width-5, 50);


                rectangle.Border = 0;

                PdfAnnotation bannerStamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamper.Writer, rectangle, null, "footer");


                bannerImage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                bannerImage.ScaleToFit(rectangle );
                bannerImage.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM | Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
               PdfAppearance app = cb.CreateAppearance(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                app.AddImage(bannerImage);
                bannerStamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
                bannerStamp.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
                stamper.AddAnnotation(bannerStamp, pageNum);
                stamper.Close();

            }
```

I am pretty sure it's something to do with the rectangle and the CreateAppearance (the number in here is the size of my image), but I am at a loss to work out what.

**EDIT**
Based on the comments I have updated my code so that my rectangle an pdfAppearance are the same size. My question still remains though-

**How can I align the banner image to be central to the rectangle?**

Comment: Your code appears undecided how large the annotation shall be. On one hand you have the constant 646x57 of the appearance, on the other hand you have (`cropbox.Width` - 100)x50 in the rectangle. Why don't you decide which size it shall be and use that size consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out!
You cannot set alignment, you must set absolute postion. This is the code now:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcFile);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true))
            {
                var cropbox = reader.GetCropBox(1);

                iTextSharp.text.Image bannerImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bannerUrl);
                var rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5, cropbox.Width-5, 50);

                rectangle.Border = 0;

                PdfAnnotation bannerStamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamper.Writer, rectangle, null, "footer");

                bannerImage.ScaleToFit(rectangle );
                bannerImage.SetAbsolutePosition((cropbox.Width - bannerImage.ScaledWidth)/2, 0); //align it center

                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                PdfAppearance app = cb.CreateAppearance(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
                app.AddImage(bannerImage);
                bannerStamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
                bannerStamp.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
                stamper.AddAnnotation(bannerStamp, pageNum);
                stamper.Close();

            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```